# Convert large array of array to associative array without loop

Tags: php, arrays, redis, amazon-elasticache, aws-php-sdk

I am using aws redis cache for quicker results instead of saving in db.
With this method

```
$result = $client->listTagsForResource([
    'ResourceName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
]);
```

Now it gives me result in given format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Key] => key1
            [Value] => string1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Key] => status
            [Value] => 1
        )

)
```

I am unable to find a function in amazon docs which can give me direct results, so I decided to search in array , but finding in very large array with loops cost me in terms of time. So is there a way to convert it in following

```
Array
(
    [key1] =>  string1,
    [status] =>  1
)
```

So I can directly access array index by using `$array['key1']`

Comment: If you're only performing one search on the result set, then first converting it to an associative array can't possibly make it faster because you will still have to pay the cost of traversal. I.e., the cost of the convert loop will never be less than the cost of one search loop.

Comment: If you want to be able to search the data this way, why don't you convert it before you write it to the cache.  This means the conversion is done once and the read is much quicker.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes you are right array_combine will take same or more time, so what should be best approach for large arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to create new array:

```
$newArray = array_combine(
                array_column($array, 'Key'), 
                array_column($array, 'Value')
);

echo $newArray['status'];
```